# Efficent search and replace program for large no of files in java

Tags: java, regex, full-text-search, performance

I have created a search and replace program using regular expression for large no of files using **eclipse ide**.In this program I have given the name of directory in which search and replace to be performed(It may have sub directories also).For small no of files it runs smoothly but for directories having 1000 of files it **hangs** in between as does nothing(even after increasing the jvm memory size).
I have used BufferedReader to read each file line by line and used regex to match the pattern in the line and then replaced it with some other text.
Can any body suggest me the possible solution(Algorithms,Library,trick,hack) for it?

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(changedFile));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        br.close();
        sb.trimToSize();
        String code = sb.toString();
        code = code.replaceAll("System", "PrintWriter");
        bw.write(code);
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
```

Comment: There are so many things you could have done wrong. How should we know without seeing any of your code?

Comment: BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(changedFile));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {sb.append(line).append("\n");
                             br.close();
   sb.trimToSize();
   String code = sb.toString();
               code = code.replaceAll("This","That");

Comment: What kind of pattern do you search for? Regexps are not fast maybe `ìndexOf` can also do what you want, just faster.

Comment: @WitVault edit your post instead of writing lots of code into a comment. Nobody will try to read that.

Comment: I've used FAR findandreplace.sourceforge.net/ you can try it an if work you can look into the source code.

Comment: not an answer to your actual question, but you should escape the parentheses in your `replaceAll` statement, because the first parameter is treated as a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the write buffer in your OS is filling up and it must wait for the data to flush to disk unless you can determine the program really is hanging up due to a bug in it.  Using the debugger is a simple way to test this or using `jstack` to take a stack trace.

> tell me exactly where is the problem.

I suspect the problem is in the speed of your hard drive. If you have a HDD which has a seek time of 8 ms;

- find the file for read 8 ms
- read the file 4-12 ms
- find the file for write 8 ms
- write the file 4-12 ms
- update filesystem journal 8 ms.

The total time take is about 32 - 48 ms, which means you can update about 20 - 30 files per second.

For <$50 you can buy a 32 GB SSD with an access time of 0.1 ms.  You can buy double the size for not much more.

- find the file for read 0.1 ms
- read the file 0.1 ms
- find the file for write 0.1 ms
- write the file 0.1 ms
- update filesystem journal 0.1 ms.

The total time might be 0.5 ms allowing you to process up to 2000 files per second.

The only reason it appears you can do more is that the OS caches reads and buffers writes, to a point.  When these are exhaused (which they seem to be fairly quickly on Windows) you are limited by the speed of the drive.

Comment: Hi can you please see the code snippet I have updated and tell me exactly where is the problem.

Comment: @WitVault I assume you have spinning hard drive. If so, see my answer.

Comment: so should I remove the flush??

Comment: @WitVault, close() calls flush(), so you can remove it but it won't make any difference. If you don't call close() the file can be corrupted.

Comment: @WitVault This is why people invest in SSD drives. A HDD can handle about 80 IOPS (IO per Second), if you have two stripped you might double this. An SSD can handle 80K - 230K IOPS (more than one thousand times faster)

Comment: Yes in India SSD is too costly

Comment: @WitVault In that case you need to be patient as you cannot make the hardware faster. :(  In the UK a small SSD is cheaper than a HDD. The only other option is to add memory as this allows you to process more files before it slows down.

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet that you have provided seems (mostly) correct to me, in the sense that it will indeed load a *whole* file into memory, perform the replacement and write it back. My suspicions for your problem:

- Your program is encountering a file that is marginal w.r.t. being loaded in the memory that is available. That would lead to the garbage collector working overtime to free-up space and could easily lead to your program appearing to be frozen.
- Your directory recursion code gets tangled-up somewhere and either blocks or iterates over the same files repeatedly.

A few suggestions:

- Check the CPU usage - is your program actually *doing* anything? Or is it deadlocked somewhere? Is your hard drive active?
- Have your program print each file name before processing. Does it stop at a specific file each time? Is it looping over the same set of files?
- Use the Eclipse debugger or a JVM monitor, such as [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html), to examine your program. What is it doing when appearing to be frozen? What is its memory usage and GC activity like?

I'm afraid that without more information on your program it would be quite difficult to provide a more specific answer...

Comment: Is there any eclipse plugin to see cpu utilization or memory usage?

Comment: @WitVault: I would suggest using VisualVM - it is bundled for free with the Oracle JDK distribution. IIRC, there *is* a similar plugin for Eclipse, called JVMMonitor, *but* VisualVM seemed to be far more stable to me...